# I need F(x,y) = xy (not x*y) e.g. x= 1, y =2 so F(x,y) = 12

Tags: functions

I just need `F(x,y)` that give me

`e.g. x= 1, y =2 so F(x,y) = 12`

Is that possible. I tried Google but not able to find a solution.

**Update**
`x and y` are integer and i do not want any build-in function rather some mathematical formula. I could have use string concatenation but that has a performance hit that I cannot effort in the application given i have tight loop over millions of values.

I tried `10x + y`  but i do not know stride length in advance and some time `y` will not fit into a stride with length `10`.

A binary bitwise solution is also acceptable. Given x and y are a 64bit integers.

Comment: And what do you need for `x = 11` and `y = 222`?

Comment: Also for `x=2.34` and `y=0.45`. On top of that I don't think this question is related to Mathematica.

Comment: …and $10x+y$ does not suit your needs?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
fF[x__Integer] := FromDigits[Join @@ IntegerDigits @ {x}]

fF[1, 2]
(* 12 *)
fF[2, 4, 65]
(* 2465 *)
```

Comment: That's certainly the way to go in Mathematica, although I remain curious, as to what exactly OP desired, as he mentioned not wanting built-in functions.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP, i just saw the OP's update re "not wanting a built-in function". Sounds like he needs something along the lines of your answer.

Answer (score 4):

In light of the update to OP, here's an approach by way of a mathematical formula.

```
(* f[x_Integer, y_Integer] := x*Power[10, Ceiling[Log[10, y]]] + y *)
```

**update** corrected function should be as follows:

```
f[x_Integer, y_Integer] := x*Power[10, Floor[Log[10, y]] + 1] + y
```

Now let's make some fake data (two sets of `10^5` 64 bit integers):

```
xlist = RandomInteger[{-2^63, 2^63 - 1}, 10^5];
ylist = RandomInteger[{-2^63, 2^63 - 1}, 10^5];
```

Let's test the performance.

```
Thread[f[xlist, ylist]] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> `6.7900095`

What about strings, as suggested by Peltio?

```
f2[x_Integer, y_Integer] := ToExpression[StringJoin[ToString[x], ToString[y]]]
Thread[f2[xlist, ylist]] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> `1.3400019`

Better, but not by orders of magnitude. Will not save you if, as you say, you're working with millions of integers.

How about @kguler 's approach?

```
f3[x_Integer, y_Integer] := FromDigits[Join @@ IntegerDigits@{x, y}]
Thread[f3[xlist, ylist]] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> `1.0800015`

Marginally better.

As we can see, the somewhat universal mathematical formula performs worst of all.

I have a hunch that packed arrays may improve performance, but it appears, that a 64-bit signed integer refuses to fit into a packed array. Also, the result would be at least of 128-bit integers. I'll think about it and update this answer if I come up with something.

Comment: I don't think `Ceiling[Log[10, y]]` will work when `y` is a power of 10, for instance if `x = y = 1` then your formula returns 2 instead of 11; try `Ceiling[Log[10, y + 1]]` or `Floor[Log[10, y]] + 1 ` instead.

Comment: @Neil you're right, that's an oversight on my part. Corrected to `Floor[...] + 1`

Answer (score 3):

Yet another way:

```
f[x_Integer, y_Integer] := x*10^IntegerLength[y] + y

f[68, 54]
```

> ```
> 6854
> ```

Or to generalize:

```
g = Fold[#1*10^IntegerLength[#2] + #2 &, {##}] &;

g[89, 68, 54]
```

> ```
> 896854
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to do that with logs and exps but then it dawned on me:

```
f[x_, y_] := ToExpression[StringJoin[ToString[x], ToString[y]]]
```

Comment: Nice! An obvious solution to a programmer but not to a mathematician ^_^